# Android: image rotation not desire to resize

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation

I have a code for rotate an ImageView, and good good.
The problem is that the size of image change in the rotate process and I desire that not happen.

The xml code of image

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBallesta"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/imgballesta"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageString"
         />
```

The code that creates the bitmap, I put this code in the declaration of class

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imgObjectImage);
```

And the code for rotate the image, this code is inluded and onTouchEvent

```
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate((float) (angle*180/Math.PI), image.getWidth(),image.getHeight());
Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
image.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
```

Thanks for the help, and for read my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a posoble solution to my problem. First I modify the size and height of my image and create the respective image for all drawable folders.
Then I use the next code for to animate the image.

```
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
img.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) (a*180/Math.PI) , img.getWidth()/2, img.getHeight()/2);
img.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Thanks for response and read this question.

Comment: are you sure about the solution, I also implemented your solution but my image is resizing when rotation occurs.

Comment: I can't remember very well, because is a old project. But if I marked this as answered I think that it works when I write de code.

Answer (score 2):

Try with my method for rotate picture :

```
public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap src, float degree) {
    // create new matrix
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // setup rotation degree
    matrix.postRotate(degree);

    // return new bitmap rotated using matrix
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Good luck!!

Comment: Nothing change, continue to modify the size of image, thanks for response